# Reading Serial Communication Visual Studios

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serial-port, backgroundworker, serial-communication

I need some help with Background worker. I am trying to read data from a serial port (works fine with a button) the problem is that I need to continuously read from the serial port, until someone presses a button (Close button) on the form to stop reading. I tried doing this by adding a loop, but it just ran infinitely and froze up the form.  I have the following code, whenever I press the button to read, a file is created, but when I press the close port button,it says

> The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or
>   an application request

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO.Ports;
    using System.IO;

    namespace SerialCommunication
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetAvaliablePortNames();
    }

    bool indicator;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\slahiri\Desktop\Data\jumbo.txt");

    void GetAvaliablePortNames()
    {
        string[] Ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        cmbPort.Items.AddRange(Ports);
    }

    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (cmbPort.Text == "" || cmbBaud.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select the Port and Baud Rates");
            }
            else
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = cmbPort.Text;
                serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cmbBaud.Text);
                serialPort1.Open();
                progressBar1.Value = 100;

                groupBox2.Enabled = true;
                btnRead.Enabled = true;

                btnOpen.Enabled = false;
                btnClose.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            txtRead.Text = "Unauthorized Acess";
        }
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.Close();
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        btnClose.Enabled = false;
        btnRead.Enabled = false;

        btnOpen.Enabled = true;
        indicator = true;


    }



    private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnRead.Text == "Read")
        {

            btnRead.Text = "Stop and Close Port";
            progressBar1.Maximum = 1000;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(progressBar1.Maximum);
            indicator = false;
        }
        else
        {

            backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; 
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();

        }
    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int max = (int)e.Argument;
            int n = 0;
            indicator = false;
            do
            {
                //write to serial writer
                sw.WriteLine(serialPort1.ReadLine());
                if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                {
                    sw.Flush();
                    sw.Close();
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
               // backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(n++);
            }

            while (indicator ==false);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            //Close Serial Writer & Messagebox
            //txtRead.Text = "Time Out!";
            MessageBox.Show("TimeOut Exception");
        }

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
         btnRead.Text = "Read";
        //close serial writer
    }

}
```

}

Comment: do you open somewhere the `SerialPort` ?

Comment: In the Open Serial Port Button, did not include because I though it was irrelevant, would you like me to add it?

Comment: it would avoid such questions ;)

Comment: It's been a while since I've done anything with the serial port, but back in the day, there used to be an oncomm event, this was the event that got triggered anytime anything happened on the port. If this event still exists, then your code should be in this event and handled according to event type.

Comment: When I am trying it the file is created, but there is nothing inside (the information that is being transmitted via Serial connection). When I click the close button the error (listed above) freezes the program and I am forced to stop the debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a do-while construct you evaluate the condition at the END!
So when you hit the `Close` button and close the SerialPort the backgroundworker is still active and running in the background trying to read from the `SerialPort`. It enters the do compartment and tries to read from a closed port, which is like running agains a closed door :) this leads to the exception.

You could solve it by

1) putting the while-evaluation on top and get rid of the `do` statement (making it a simple while-loop). This way the `serialPort.ReadLine` will not be executed anymore, because you set `indicator = true;` when hitting the close button.

May be in this case you should put the setting of `indicator` as the first line before closing the port:

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        indicator = true;
        serialPort1.Close();
```

Or

2) put an extra if clause that makes sure to read only if the port is open!

```
if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
{
    sw.WriteLine(serialPort1.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Shankulah60 You are welcome, you can also check with `if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)` when you hit the close button, and then close the port. Because then you can be sure that he is not trying to read from the port